# Why is it "get" and not "gets", in "watch her get hit"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, meaning-in-context, grammatical-number

> He likes to watch her get hit.

vs.

> He likes to watch her gets hit.

No matter how much I research, I still can't explain simply why *get* is correct and *gets* isn't.

Here's what I think, though. It's a combination of issues:

*get hit* is *having gotten hit* in present tense.

It's passive, because we don't specify the agent that is hitting her.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice

> "The subject of a sentence or clause featuring the passive voice denotes the recipient of the action (the patient) rather than the performer (the agent). The passive voice in English is formed periphrastically: the usual form uses the auxiliary verb be (or get) together with the past participle of the main verb.

So the *get* here is definitely acting passively.

Ignoring tense: *get hit* ~= *be hit* ~= *being hit*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Gerunds_with_a_specified_subject

So, the key phrase in question is in passive voice (*get* is a helper verb), and
*get hit* similarly acts nominalized.

*get hit* here can be substituted with *beatdown*:

> We're watching (that someone received a) beatdown.

vs.

> We're watching (whose?) beatdown.

In either case, it's still an argument between *her* being a direct object or acting possessively, so that's why it can't be *she*.

And because you can use any of *them*, *her*, *him*, *it* with *get* (and never *gets* in this context,) it just is.

Comment: I don’t understand any part of your argumentation, except that you correctly identify ‘get hit’ as a passive construction. Note that _get_ is not “acting passively”, it is simply the auxiliary verb that signifies that _hit_ is in the passive voice. The verb _watch_, like many other verbs (especially sense verbs), can take an _infinitive argument_. “Watch [someone] be/do/say/get/take/kick [something]”: the verb is always in the _infinitive_. ‘Get hit’ is a verbal phrase; you can’t just substitute it for a noun phrase ‘beatdown’. ‘Get hit’ is also not ‘having gotten hit’ in the present tense; ->

Comment: -> that would be ‘getting hit’. It is not a present tense of anything, ’cause it’s not a present tense at all.

Comment: It is *"He likes to watch her* **get** *hit"* for the same reason it is *"He likes to watch her* **be** *hit"*. The "get/be" is the plain form of a verb. It does not have primary tense, thus it is neither "present tense" nor "past tense". The plain form of the verb is used in infinitive and subjunctive and imperative constructions. You've asked good questions, and to get good answers it'd probably be best for you to find yourself a vetted grammar source, such as Huddleston and Pullum's 2005 textbook, *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*. The stuff on the net is dubious at best.

Comment: I think your problem is between the use of **she** and **her**.  *He likes to watch **her get** hit.*  OR  *He likes to watch while **she gets** hit.*"

Comment: Your example may have attracted more interest had it been less obviously repugnant. Couldn't you have made it 'He loved to watch her get sawn in half'.

Answer (score 2):

Because *watch* is one of the many verbs which takes an **infinitive** verb (in this case, an infinitive without *to*). That is also why it has *her*, not *she*.

In the case of *watch*, there is actually another sense of *watch* which takes *that* and a finite verb. It means "take care that".

So

> Watch her get hit.

(with the infinitive *get*) is about looking at the act of hitting, whereas

> Watch that she doesn't get hit

(with the finite *doesn't*) is about taking care to avoid an act of hitting.

[I could have made it more parallel by saying *Watch that she gets hit*, but that is such an unlikely thing to say, that it is difficult to make sense of it: if I heard it, I would probably assume it was a non-English speaker trying to say *watch her get hit*.]